# Access troubles to db2 console

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

i'm facing access problems to the db2 console (ibm-cloud).
i got this message :

**HWCUSR0079E: Impossible to acces user information. Motif : HWCCON0048E: Failed to get connection profile crn:v1:bluemix:public:dashdb-for-transactions:us-south:a/16421fa67dc942ea96e562ff547b457a:ed7c96b2-28b4-4d9b-9bc4-46567241774b:: because Not Found.**

Need help please , thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue as you. And I checked View Cloud Status from resource list:
**[image: strong text]**

I suspect their servicehave interruption.

https://cloud.ibm.com/status?item=INC4148101

Also, if you search against the internet and Coursera, you will find that we are not alone.